# How to create a windows application that will read/edit different excel files?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, excel, winapi

My goal is to create a simple (one file) executable for windows environment that will open a pretty simple form.
The form will read data from excel files and after the user fills out the form and submit it - the application will write the data to a different excel file.

This will be used by different users in a shared drive.
I have programming experience with C/C++/C#/.Net/Python and other languages but never really created a windows program.

Any ideas where should i start? (a relevant tutorial would be greatly appreciated)

Thanks!

Comment: IMHO, vb.net provides the simplest way of manipulating `Excel.Application`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read and edit Excel files look into the Microsoft Office Interop libraries: class library documentation is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel).  Regarding tutorials, the best approach would be to search the web and see what you can find.  A couple I found are:

- C# Excel Interop: http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel
- How to automate Microsoft Excel from Microsoft Visual C#.NET: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084

Good luck!  :)

Answer (score 0):

OK. There are multiple ways.

You can make use of a RichTextBox and write it down to a excel file using `Stream` or even static methods that come with `File` class (only if you are dealing with lesser data and not worry much about performance).

If you are supposed to take care of formatting as well, take a look at `Interop`.